# Alphanumeric sorting in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sorting

I am selecting the column names from a table with the following query.

```
SELECT column_name FROM   all_tab_cols
WHERE  table_name = 'TBL1' AND column_name like 'INFORMATION%'
order by column_name
```

The resultset is like

```
INFORMATION1
INFORMATION10
INFORMATION11
INFORMATION12
.
.
.
INFORMATION2
INFORMATION20
```

Now, I want it to be sorted like

```
INFORMATION1
INFORMATION2
INFORMATION3
INFORMATION4
.
.
.
INFORMATION19
INFORMATION20
```

How to achieve this without being much cpu-intense??
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a numeric-sensitive collation, if Oracle supports that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Order first by string length, then by string:

```
SELECT column_name 
FROM all_tab_cols
WHERE table_name = 'TBL1' 
  AND column_name LIKE 'INFORMATION%'
ORDER BY LENGTH(column_name), column_name;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7/6520/0)**</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

> How to achieve this without being much cpu-intense?

**REGEX** is CPU intensive and slower as compared to old **SUBSTR**. Use **SUBSTR** to get the digit part and use it in the **ORDER BY**.

Also, since you are filtering rows only with `INFORMATION` string, you need only one ORDER BY on the digit part.

```
SELECT column_name FROM   all_tab_cols
WHERE  table_name = 'TBL1' AND column_name like 'INFORMATION%'
ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(column_name, LENGTH('INFORMATION') +1));
```

You can hard-code the **LENGTH** as `12`.

```
ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(column_name, 12))
```

Here is the **[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/94a448/8)**.

Comment: Both of yours and Bob Jarvis 's answer works great. But it seems that lad2025 's solution is slightly faster. Thanks

Comment: @Avishek I compared the explain plans, they are exactly same. So use any of the two queries, would perform same.

Answer (score 2):

Change the ORDER BY to

```
ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(COLUMN_NAME, 12))
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
SELECT column_name FROM   all_tab_cols
WHERE  table_name = 'TBL1' AND column_name like 'INFORMATION%'
ORDER  BY regexp_substr(column_name,'[[:alpha:]]'),
to_number(regexp_substr(column_name, '\d+'))
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/94a448/1)**

Answer (score 0):

SELECT column FROM table ORDER BY CAST(column AS DECIMAL), column; -->mysql

SELECT column FROM table ORDER BY CAST(regexp_substr(column, '^\d*') AS DECIMAL), column; -->oracle

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.